# cannot convert between nested templated types

Tags: c++, templates, handler

I am trying to write a message handler whose Base classes are

1-Handler base class

2-Handler Factory that generates proper handler for a proper message type

3-and a base generic class for message

their code is like this:

```
#include <map>
#include<iostream>
//Base Handler
template<class MSG>
class Handler
{
    MSG message;
public:
    Handler(MSG message):message(message){
    }

    virtual void handle() = 0;
    MSG getMessage()
    {
        return message;
    }
};

//Base Handler Factory
template<class MSG>
class HandlerFactory {
public:
    virtual Handler<MSG> * create(MSG & message) = 0;
};

//Base message
template<class T>
class Message
{
    T messageType;
public:
    T getMessageType()
    {
        return messageType;
    }

    void setMessageType(T messageType_)
    {
        messageType = messageType_;
    }
};
```

//Then, based on the message type, I write subclass for every base class:

```
//my custom types
enum MessageType
{
    ANNOUNCE,
    KEY_SEND,
    KEY_REQUEST
};

//my first custom message format
class MyMessage_1 : public Message<MessageType>
{
    //...
};

//my first custom handler
class MyMessageHandler_1 : public Handler<MyMessage_1>
{

public:
    MyMessageHandler_1(MyMessage_1 &message_): Handler<MyMessage_1>(message_)
    {
    }
    void handle(){}
};

//my custom handler factory
class MyHandlerFactory : public HandlerFactory<Message<MessageType> > {
    Handler<Message<MessageType> > *value;
public:
    MyHandlerFactory(){};
    Handler<Message<MessageType>  > * create(Message<MessageType> & message){
        switch (message.getMessageType())
        {
        case ANNOUNCE:
            MyMessage_1 t1;
            value = new MyMessageHandler_1(t1);//error here
            break;
            //etc. etc.
        default:
            value = 0;
            break;
        };
        return value;
    };

};
```

//let's put a main so you can easily compile it

```
int main()
{

}
```

the problem is when, in switch-case clause, I try to create an instance of a handler for one of my custom message classes, I get the following error:

```
templateArgList.cpp: In member function ‘virtual Handler<Message<MessageType> >* MyHandlerFactory::create(Message<MessageType>&)’:
templateArgList.cpp:86:37: error: cannot convert ‘MyMessageHandler_1*’ to ‘Handler<Message<MessageType> >*’ in assignment
```

I was under the impression that:
`Handler<Message<MessageType>  > *`  can be casted as follows:

```
MyMessageHandler_1-> Handler<MyMessage_1>
                             ^
                             |
                     `Message<MessageType>`  which finally gives me:
                                                `Handler<Message<MessageType>  >`  :P
```

Am I wrong? of course I am, why would I get the above error then :))
I just don't know why and how to fix it.
Therefore I will appreciate if you kindly help me with it.

thanks very much for your kind help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a very simple program that is analogous to what you have done, but without the nested templates so that it's understandable:

```
#include <vector>

class A {
};

class B : public A {
};

int main() {

   std::vector<A>* va;
   va = new std::vector<B>;

}
```

And indeed, g++ gives the error:

```
error: cannot convert ‘std::vector<B>*’ to ‘std::vector<A>*’ in assignment
```

This should be clear -- a vector of A's is not the same as a vector of B's, even though B inherits from A. To be able to take advantage of inheritance, you have to have pointers to the objects that are related. For example:

```
int main() {
   std::vector<A*> va(3);
   for (int i=0; i<3; ++i) {
      va[i] = new B;
   }
}
```

The analogy here is:

```
std::vector< > ----> Handler< >
A              ----> Message<MessageType>
B              ----> MyMessage_1
```

By the way, did you realize that you define a variable named `message` in both MyMessageHandler_1 and also in Handler<>? This will cause MyMessageHandler_1::message to hide Handler<>::message. I'm not sure if this is what you want.

Also.. you might want to look into [the Twisted package for Python](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/index.html), as it might be well suited to the application you're building. (If you don't mind using Python.)

---

Question: "any suggestion to alter my code?"

Response:

Well, I would try removing the templates and enjoying the power of inheritance. The Handler class can accept a `Message` object (or reference or pointer), as both of these are base classes. The `HandlerFactory`'s create would also accept a `Message` object. Then you can proceed with the `Message` class having an `enum MessageType` type member variable and using switch inside `HandlerFactor` to determine the correct `Handler`-derived class to create.

Or instead of the enum, you could exploit inheritance even further by adding a "`NewHandler()`" function to `Message`, which would be pure virtual in `Message` and would be defined in the derived class. This way, you wouldn't need a switch -- each type of message knows what `Handler` it needs, and the factor simply calls `message->NewHandler()`.

...It's a bit difficult to determine whether you need to use templates or not because I'm not sure where your project is headed. However, as a rough rule of thumb, it's a good idea to use templates when (a) you want to use equivalent blocks of code for different types and (b) you can't use inheritance to accomplish it. The `std::vector<>` is a good example -- the behavior of `std::vector<int>` and `std::vector<float>` is the same, but `int`'s and `float`'s aren't related by any common base, so rather than rewrite the code for a VectorI and VectorF, the compiler is asked to rewrite the code instead.

So far, it looks like you can exploit inheritance to do what you want. It has the added bonus of making it easier for other people to read your code, as well. :)

Comment: thanks. I am not able to use python at this moment. I actually tried to copy this one from a java source. I now understand the problem, thanks to your simplification. any suggestion to alter my code?

Comment: I implemented your solution in http://codepad.org/HM0LE9pC . can you please have look to see if it is ok? (I left a small question for you inside the code) thanks a lot.

Comment: Looks ok; just a couple of comments. MH_ANNOUNCE's ctor could accept a M_ANNOUNCE* instead of a Message* -- you just have to move the M_ANNOUNCE class definition above MH_ANNOUCE, so that the compiler knows M_ANNOUNCE inherits from Message (the forward declaration doesn't tell it about inheritance). Second, you can move `return message->newHandler();` into the base `HandlerFactory` class. Currently, you could remove `MyHandlerFactory` entirely. Finally, take care that whoever calls `create` will eventually see that the Handler gets deleted!

Comment: for the 1st suggestion, seems I can't do that coz I cant create a  MH_ANNOUCE with an argument(`this`). I updated the above like

Comment: Ah true, you would need to put the interface and implementations in separate files to have a hope for that. But in any case, it should be fine to pass the base class `Message`. `MH_ANNOUNCE` can always try to cast up if it needs to.

Comment: Thanks. it was a very helpful discussion.